# Regular Expression does not remove html comment?

Tags: regex, vb.net

I have the following string:

`<TD><!-- 1.91 -->6949<!-- 9.11 --></TD>`

I want to end up with:

`<TD>6949/TD>`

but instead I end up with just the tags and no information:

```
<TD></TD>
```

This is the regular expression I am using:

```
RegEx.Replace("<TD><!-- 1.91 -->6949<!-- 9.11 --></TD>","<!--.*-->","")
```

Can someone explain how to keep the numbers and remove just what the comments.  Also if possible, can someone explain why this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.*` is a greedy qualifier which matches as much as possible.
It's matching everything until the *last* `-->`.

Change it to `.*?`, which is a lazy qualifier.

Comment: Great thanks.  So when I use the .*, it doesn't care if anything is in the middle, it keeps on going until it finds the last --> and removes every character in between including the <!-- and -->

Answer (score 2):

`.*` is greedy so it will match as many characters as possible. In this case the opening of the first comment until the end of the second. Changing it to `.*?` or `[^>]*` will fix it as the `?` makes the match lazy. Which is to say it will match as few characters as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Parsing HTML with Regex is always going to be tricky. Instead, use something like [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) which will allow you to query and parse html in a structured manner.